# Google Cloud Platform - can't add scope (script.external_request scope)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a verified OAuth Consent Screen under Google Cloud Platform (https://console.cloud.google.com) and now I need to add a scope. The problem is I can check boxes and use ADD to add any scope in the list, but I can't add a different one:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
```

[image]

What can I do to add this?

```
../auth/script.external_request
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just click on the option **manually paste** [image: manually paste option]

A textbox will be shown. There, paste your scope and Click **Add**.

[image]

The scope should be shown in your OAuth consent screen after that.

[image]

## March, 2022 UPDATE

The OAuth Consent screen now shows all the active scopes for your application divided in *Non-sensitive*, *Sensitive* and *Restricted*.

If you need to add a Scope, just click on *ADD OR REMOVE SCOPES*, a new screen will be shown at the right. There, paste your scope if you don't find it in the *default list*:

[image]

Click on *ADD TO TABLE*, it will be checked by default:

[image]

Finally, click on *UPDATE* and it will now be shown in the respective scope:

[image]